# Display number of pages in Word ML

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word, xslt-1.0, wordml

I want to display total number of pages on the first page of word document, that is formin with WORD ML template. 
I know how to display current page number and total number of pages in a footer. It looks like:

```
<w:ftr w:type="odd">
     <w:p>
        <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="007924AD">
           <w:rPr>
              <w:rStyle w:val="a6" />
                 <w:color w:val="777777" />
           </w:rPr>
           <w:instrText> PAGE </w:instrText>
         </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:ftr>
```

But how can I display PAGE or NUMPAGES not in a footer but in the body of a page?
Is it possible?

Comment: use bookmarks and not page numbers.

Comment: @KevinBrown, what do you mean? I haven't caught your idea. I need to display total page count in the document, how can I manage to do this with bookmarks?

Comment: put a bookmark on the last page and retrieve the page num er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The field NUMPAGES is forming correctly but the number of pages is not updated automatically. You must force it update in one of the following ways:

click on the autofield and and select update field from the context menu
print preview the document - the field will be updated
save the document as pdf, for example